# R: converting each row of a data frame into a list item

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore, dataframe, plyr

I have a number of operations on data frames which I would like to speed up using `mclapply()` or other `lapply()` like functions. One of the easiest ways for me to wrestle with this is to make each row of the data frame a small data frame in a list. I can do this pretty easily with `plyr` like this:

```
df <- data.frame( a=rnorm(1e4), b=rnorm(1e4))
require(plyr)
system.time(myList <- alply( df, 1, function(x) data.frame(x) ))
```

Once I have my data as a list I can easily do things like:

```
mclapply( myList, function(x) doSomething(x$a) )
```

This works swimmingly, but I have quite a lot of data and the `adply()` step is quite slow. I tried using the multicore parallel backend on the `adply` step, but it never used more than one processor even though I had registered 8. I'm suspicious the parallel option may not work with this type of problem.

Any tips on how to make this faster? Maybe a base R solution?

Comment: Why don't you do `alply(df, 1, function(x) doSomething(x), .parallel = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use `split`.  It's a few times faster than your `adply` line.

```
> system.time(myList <- alply( df, 1, function(x) data.frame(x) ))
   user  system elapsed 
   7.53    0.00    7.57 
> system.time( splitList <- split(df, 1:NROW(df)) )
   user  system elapsed 
   1.73    0.00    1.74 
>
```

I suspect the parallel backend on `adply` is only for function evaluation (not splitting and re-combining).

UPDATE:
If you can convert your data.frame to a matrix, the solution below will be über-fast.  You may be able to use `split`, but it will drop names and return a vector in each list element.

```
> m <- as.matrix(df)
> system.time( matrixList <- lapply(1:NROW(m), function(i) m[i,,drop=FALSE]) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02
> str(matrixList[[1]])
 num [1, 1:2] -0.0956 -1.5887
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
> system.time( matrixSplitList <- split(m, 1:NROW(m)) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> str(matrixSplitList[[1]])
 num [1:2] -0.0956 -1.5887
```

Comment: I think your conclusion about the splitting and combining is correct.

Comment: clearly my lesson for today is, "everything is faster on matrices"

Comment: A fairer comparison is `system.time(myList <- alply( df, 1, identity ))` but it still takes too long :(

Comment: It should be possible to make it as fast as split, if only R had a fast function to subscript an object by an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
jdList <- split(df, 1:nrow(df))

> class(jdList[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"

> system.time(jdList <- split(df, 1:nrow(df)))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.67    0.02    1.70 
> system.time(myList <- alply( df, 1, function(x) data.frame(x) ))
   user  system elapsed 
    7.2     0.0     7.3
```